# rails bulk assigning sequence_numbers in console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to assign an incremental sequence number to the trades of my users, so that each user will have something like the following:

```
user 1
  trade sequence 1
  trade sequence 2
  trade sequence 3
  trade sequence 4
user 2
  trade sequence 1
  trade sequence 2
  trade sequence 3
```

and so on.

I'm trying to do this with the following command:

```
User.all.each { |u| u.trades.each_with_index {|t, i|  t.sequence_number = i+1; t.save} }
```

It doesn't work though, the console shows me it does a ton of sql queries, but rollbacks everything. Here's one block from the SQL queries:

```
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Trade Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` 
  Trade Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` ORDER BY `trades`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Trade Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `trades` WHERE (`trades`.`user_id` = BINARY 1 AND `trades`.`id` != 18 AND `trades`.`sequence_number` = 29) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

It's not updating a thing.

If I change the command to:

```
 User.all.each { |u| u.trades.each_with_index {|t, i|  puts [t.id, t.sequence_number = i + 1].to_s} }
```

it prints correctly the trade ids and the sequence numbers:

```
[1, 1]
[3, 2]
[4, 3]
[5, 4]
[6, 5]
[7, 6]
[8, 7]
[9, 8]
[10, 9]
[12, 10]
[13, 11]
[14, 12]
[15, 13]
[16, 14]
[17, 15]
[18, 16]
[19, 17]
```

but it's missing the `t.save`

I've tried also with `t.save!`:

```
User.all.each { |u| u.trades.each_with_index {|t, i|  t.sequence_number = i+1; t.save!} }
  User Load (57.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
  Trade Load (25.3ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` WHERE `trades`.`user_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Trade Load (6.1ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` 
  Trade Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` ORDER BY `trades`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Trade Exists (11.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `trades` WHERE (`trades`.`user_id` = BINARY 1 AND `trades`.`id` != 1 AND `trades`.`sequence_number` = 29) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Trade Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` 
  Trade Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` ORDER BY `trades`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Trade Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `trades` WHERE (`trades`.`user_id` = BINARY 1 AND `trades`.`id` != 3 AND `trades`.`sequence_number` = 29) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User has already been taken
```

Comment: `trade.save` is returning false due to a validation error, try using `trade.save!` so you can see what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by another piece of code, responsible for initializing the sequence numbers for the objects:

Trade definition now contains:

```
  before_validation :assign_sequence_number

  def assign_sequence_number
    unless sequence_number
      self.sequence_number = Trade.all.empty? ? 1 : Trade.last.sequence_number + 1
    end
  end
```

and now it works :) thanks.